# ActiveRecordのdestroyで発行されるSQLが不完全な状態となる

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

質問の前にテーブルの構成を示します。

## 構成

### テーブル

- users … ユーザ情報を保持するテーブル
- entries … はてなブックマークのエントリー情報を保持するテーブル
- laters … ユーザが”あとで読む”に設定したエントリー情報を保持するテーブル

### リレーション

- users … has_many :laters
- entries … has_many :laters
- laters … belongs_to :user、belongs_to :entry

---

## 質問

ユーザに紐づくlatersテーブルのレコードを削除する実装がうまくいきません。
削除の実装は簡略化すると、下記のようになります。

### 実装

```
User.find(1).laters.where({:entry_id => 1}).first.destroy
```

この実装で動かすと下記のようなSQLが発行されます。

### 発行されるSQL

```
DELETE FROM laters WHERE laters.'' = NULL
```

latersのレコードが取得できていないのかと思い確認しましたが、レコードは取得されていました。
何が原因で不完全なSQLとなっているか分かりますでしょうか。

---

## ソースコード

Githubにソースコードを上げています。
https://github.com/hogesuke/tech-book

### 該当箇所

https://github.com/hogesuke/tech-book/blob/master/app.rb#L221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

解決しました。

まず、前提となるテーブルのアソシエーションが間違っていました。
（修正前）
users … has_many :laters
entries … has_many :laters
laters … belongs_to :user、belongs_to :entry

（修正後）
users … has_many :entries, :through => laters
entries … has_many :users, :through => laters
laters … belongs_to :user、belongs_to :entry

latersを中間テーブルとし、userとentryを結びつけるのが正しいアソシエーションでした。
そして、userとentryの紐付けの削除は、下記のようにすることで実現できました。

```
user.entries.destroy(entry)
```

お騒がせしました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hogesuke/tech-book/blob/master/db/create_table.sql#L44

CREATE TABLE laters の時に id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
漏れてませんか？これ追加すればいけると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

idの追加については試してみましたが解決しませんでした。

※その後、別の方法で解決しました…すみません